# perl regx , pick word after the word connect

Tags: perl

This is my log

```
connect
called
menu
transfer
disconnect
connect
called
transfer
disconnect
```

i want to pick the word, when the word exactly next to , 
When the word like

### connect

menu
transfer
disconnect means,

i should pick the word **transfer**,

if my flow like

connect
called
transfer
disconnect

then i dont want to pick the word **transfer**,

Comment: This is not a grammatical sentence. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coud try something like:

Updated to standard Perl distribution :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $count = 1 if $_ eq 'connect';
    if ($count == 3) {
        print "2 words after is : $_\n";
        $count = 0;
    }
    $count++ if $count;
}


__DATA__
connect
called
menu
transfer
disconnect
connect
called
transfer
disconnect
```

**output:**

```
2 words after is : menu
2 words after is : transfer
```

Comment: Can you show how to do that using the standard Perl distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex to solve this will assume that you have your log file in a single variable. Provided that your log file is not very large you can do this as follows:

```
use File::Slurp qw(slurp);
my $log = slurp('path/to/logfile');
```

Or if you prefer not to use a non-standard Perl module for this:

```
{
  local $/;
  open my $fh, '<', 'path/to/logfile' or die $!;
  my $log = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}
```

To get the instances where the word after transfer matches 'connect' but only where the flow is `menu -> transfer -> ...` you can do the following:

```
while ( $log =~ m{menu\s+transfer\s+(\w*connect\w*)}g ) {
    print "transfer -> $1\n";
}
```

Comment: How do you do that in standard Perl?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use Regex? It is not a good use case. Just

```
while (<>) { chomp; last if ($_ eq 'connect'); }
$_ = <>;
print;
```

would do.